# Assertion for constructor variables

Tags: java, constructor, assert, assertions

I am trying use assertions on a constructor in a abstract class, the String variable thename cannot be null or empty and the int variable thesize cannot be negative or zero here is how I tried to do it but the test case I was provided does not pass. How would I assert the conditions for the constructor?

```
public abstract class AbstractItem implements Item{

    private int size;
    private String name;

    public AbstractItem(String thename, int thesize){
        assert thename != null;
        assert thename.length() > 0;
        assert thesize > 0;
        name = thename;
        size = thesize;
    } 

    public final int getSize(){
        return size;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Stupid question: have you enabled assertions when running your code?

Comment: You have a test case, please show it, too!

Comment: Why have assertions in the class to be tested, instead of the test case itself?  Perhaps throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` here in the constructor would be more appropriate, if the value passed in is not acceptable.  Your test case code should be making the assertions.

Comment: Thanks Laf i did't have them enabled everything is working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**Enabling and Disabling Assertions**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#enable-disable)
>
> **By default, assertions are disabled at runtime**. Two command-line switches allow you to selectively enable or disable assertions.
>
> To enable assertions at various granularities, use the `-enableassertions`, or `-ea`, switch. To disable assertions at various granularities, use the `-disableassertions`, or `-da`, switch. You specify the granularity with the arguments that you provide to the switch:

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring, you could also use their Assert, it comes with handy error messages too, so you can have a humanly readable error for why an assertion failed.  Here is a snippet from Spring's ACL library, if sid is null, you'll get a nice error message saying so.

```
public Long createOrRetrieveSidPrimaryKey(Sid sid, boolean allowCreate) {
    Assert.notNull(sid, "Sid required");
    // more code here ....
}
```